# Testing for ascii characters whose value is > 127 in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, case, wchar

I have some data like this:

`2s  ²S  1/2 0
2p  ²P° 1/2 160015
        3/2 163990
3s  ²S  1/2 1682700
3p  ²P° 1/2 1726520
        3/2 1727830
3d  ²D  3/2 1743500
        5/2 1743890
4s  ²S  1/2 2252600
4p  ²P° 3/2 2270150
        1/2 2270150
4d  ²D  3/2 2277380
        5/2 2277700
4f  ²F° 5/2 2278060
        7/2 2278140
5s  ²S  1/2 2511600
5p  ²P° 3/2 2520900
        1/2 2520900
...`

I read this data in to a variable defined by this type:

```
typedef enum
{
s=0,
p=1,
d=2,
f=3,
g=4,
h=5,
i=6,
k=7,
l=8,
m=9,
n=10,
o=11,
q=12,
r=13,
t=14,
u=15,
v=16,
w=17,
x=18,
y=19,
z=20
} aqn; /* azimuthal quantum number */

typedef struct
{
char *config;
char *term;
int n;          /* principle quantum number */
aqn l;          /* azimuthal quantum number */
float j;
double level; /* energy level, in cm^-1 */
} nist_t;   /* NIST data type */
```

The variable is declared as `nist_t *nist;`

As you can see, the second column of the data will be stored in `nist->term`.

Suppose I have the following declaration:  `unsigned short int S`

I need to get some information from `nist->term`.  Specifically, if the first character is a '1' or '¹', then I need to set `S=1`.

If the first character of `nist->term` is a '2' or '²', then I need set `S=2`.

If the first character of `nist->term` is a '3' or '³', then I need to set `S=3`.

I tried it with a `switch`:

```
switch(nist[ix].term[0])
{
    case '1': S=1;
              break;
    case '¹': S=1;
              break;
    case '2': S=2;
              break;
    case '²': S=2;
              break;
    ... (and so on)
```

It doesn't work (in fact, it won't even compile).  I found out that the range of a `char` is -127 to 127.  And '¹' has the value 185d; '²' has the value 178d; and '³' has the value 179d.

I tried casting the string to `(unsigned int)`, and the compiler still complains about the `case` statements.

I tried changing the field in the data structure to `unsigned char`.  But then my program didn't compile because of data type conflicts in so many other places in the code where `nist.term` is used.

Despite the data type for the variable `term` being out of range for the data it holds, it still prints it out correctly.

So, looking for suggestions on how to convert the first character in that string to an integer.

Thanks.

Comment: Technically characters above 127 is not [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), it's usually called [extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) but the actual characters are different from platform to platform that uses it, and could also be different depending on locale settings.

Comment: If you print the "ASCII" value of each character in each of your strings, you might be on to a surprise. If it's encoded as UTF-8, the non-ASCII characters will actually be represented by a multibyte sequence: this means that you won't be able to use a `switch` on a single char to match them.

Comment: To solve this, use the *number* in your `case`. It does not matter if you use the negative or unsugned version (which one depends on the rest of your code). By way of documentation, write the character it represents into a comment following each `case` line.

Comment: You should be making the translation at the point where you are reading the data in from the file.  In other words, if the file contains `185d`, then store `'1'` in `nist.term`.

Comment: Dealing with extended and unicode characters in C can be cumbersome. For your particular problem, it sounds like you don't actually care if the superscript or regular number is used. Consider pre-processing your input using another tool like 'awk' or 'sed' to replace the superscripts with their ASCII equivalents.

Comment: The numbers should be superscripted.  However, in the data file, if it's 4 or 5, there is no superscript for that.  But those numbers are not encountered often.  Singlet, doublet and triplet states are that, with which we deal mostly.  And these character strings are also written into another data file, after the numbers are processed.  What I'm trying to do is write a program to pre-select certain data.  A certain range of `n`, a certain range of `l`, and a certain `S` (spin states, which are either singlets, doublets, triplets, etc...). How do I use a number in my `case`?

Comment: Your code sees the character `²` as the number `178`. If directly comparing the *character* is a problem in your code, use `case 178:`. Referring to the literal character means your source code needs to have the exact same encoding as your input (and it also introduces the signed/unsiged problems you refer to).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem thusly:

```
nist_t *prtnist_r(nist_t *nist,unsigned short int n_low,unsigned short int n_high, unsigned short int l_low, unsigned short int l_high, unsigned short int degeneracy)
{
unsigned short int a=0; /* used as index counter */
unsigned short int spin_multiplicity=0; /* spin_multiplitiy=2S+1 */

while((NULL!=nist[a].config) && (NULL!=nist[a].term))
{
    if((nist[a].term[0]==-62 && nist[a].term[1]==-71) || nist[a].term[0]==49)
        spin_multiplicity=1;
    if((nist[a].term[0]==-62 && nist[a].term[1]==-78) || nist[a].term[0]==50)
        spin_multiplicity=2;
    if((nist[a].term[0]==-62 && nist[a].term[1]==-77) || nist[a].term[0]==51)
        spin_multiplicity=3;
    if(nist[a].term[0]==52)
        spin_multiplicity=4;
    if(nist[a].term[0]==53)
        spin_multiplicity=5;

    if(nist[a].config[0]!='-')
    {
        if(nist[a].n>=n_low && nist[a].n<=n_high && nist[a].l>=l_low && nist[a].l<=l_high)
        {
            if(degeneracy==0 || degeneracy==spin_multiplicity)
            {
                (void)fprintf(stderr,"%s\t%d\t%d\t%s\t%14.8e\n",nist[a].config,nist[a].n,nist[a].l,nist[a].term,nist[a].level);
            }
        }
    }
    else
        (void)fprintf(stderr,"%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%14.8e\n","Limit","--","--","--",nist[a].level);
    ++a;
}
return nist;
}
```

Comment: FYI only: your double values for the Superscript 1 indicate your input file is not "ASCII" or some Windows or other character encoding, but rather UTF-8. The double codes match [Superscript 1 in UTF8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b9/index.htm) (they appear to be negative because your default `char` is signed.)